# How do I clear cookies with different domains?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cookies, model-view-controller

I am developing a .net core mvc web application with the same site cookies. And I would like to clear all cookies after the user logged out. Please refer to the image:

[image]

I have tried like this:

```
foreach (var cookie in HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
{
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
}
```

But it detects and deletes only one domain cookie which is `https://localhost:7018`. How can I delete all the cookies with different domains under the `Cookies` section? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to cookies that are not part of your domain.
From RFC 6265:

> The user agent will reject cookies unless the Domain attribute
> specifies a scope for the cookie that would include the origin server.
> For example, the user agent will accept a cookie with a Domain
> attribute of "example.com" or of "foo.example.com" from
> foo.example.com, but the user agent will not accept a cookie with a
> Domain attribute of "bar.example.com" or of "baz.foo.example.com".

Your origin is "localhost", so your server can only write cookies for that.